# I can't verify user with jwt

Tags: php, jwt

I am trying to authenticate with Jwt.
I found many examples about Jwt, but there is a place I don't understand.
I can easily generate tokens using the library, but I cannot verify
here is the library i use

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt
```

I'm creating a token

```
   // Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}


require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT; 
define('SECRET_KEY','Super-Secret-Key'); 
define('ALGORITHM','HS256');  


$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$action = $_GET['action'];
```

login.php

```
   if ($action == 'login') {

 $email = 'freaky@jolly.com';
 $password = '12345678';


if($email == "freaky@jolly.com" && $password == "12345678"){

     $iat = time(); // time of token issued at
     $nbf = $iat + 10; //not before in seconds
     $exp = $iat + 60; // expire time of token in seconds

     $token = array(
         "iss" => "http://example.org",
         "aud" => "http://example.com",
         "iat" => $iat,
         "nbf" => $nbf,
         "exp" => $exp,
             "data" => array(
             "id" => 11,
             "email" => $email
         )
     );

    http_response_code(200);

    $jwt = JWT::encode($token, SECRET_KEY);


     $data_insert=array(
         'access_token' => $jwt, 
         'id'   => '007',
         'name' => 'Jolly',
         'time' => time(),
         'username' => 'FreakyJolly', 
         'email' => 'contact@freakyjolly.com', 
         'status' => "success",
         'message' => "Successfully Logged In"
     );


 }else{
     $data_insert=array(
     "data" => "0",
     "status" => "invalid",
     "message" => "Invalid Request"
     ); 
 } 

} else if($action == 'stuff'){

    if (! isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])) {
        exit('Please provide a key to verify');
    }
    $jwt = $_SERVER['argv'][1];

    try {
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, SECRET_KEY, array(ALGORITHM));
        print_r($decoded);

    }catch (Exception $e){

     http_response_code(401);
     $data_insert=array(
     //"data" => $data_from_server,
     "jwt" => $jwt,
     "status" => "error",
     "message" => $e->getMessage()
     );

   } 
}

echo json_encode($data_insert);
```

Create Token: http://www.ismailcakir.com/jwt/test2.php?action=login

```
{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9leGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg2NDM4NTg4LCJuYmYiOjE1ODY0Mzg1OTgsImV4cCI6MTU4NjQzODY0OCwiZGF0YSI6eyJpZCI6MTEsImVtYWlsIjoiZnJlYWt5QGpvbGx5LmNvbSJ9fQ.NylRpDkb4cLMxMGAg9ovmLerNf0dLPBHegqmPRDRxlE","id":"007","name":"Jolly","time":1586438588,"username":"FreakyJolly","email":"contact@freakyjolly.com","status":"success","message":"Successfully Logged In"}
```

Stuff: http://www.ismailcakir.com/jwt/test2.php?action=stuff

Here I get the warning that the argv variable is undefined and I can't call the token you created.
After creating the token, I need to be able to call it without using a cookie or session.
I tried many methods but I could not understand how to take.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php):

> Note: This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is disabled.

Which most likely is your case. You can enable this in the config or alternatively use `$_SERVER` superglobal which I recommend as this is immune to config differences and always works (incl. CLI):

```
$jwt = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
```

Same for `$argc`.

Comment: when i do this i see the returned result is null , ["argv"]=> array(0) { } ["argc"]=> int(0)

Comment: Also, I can see that the register_argc_argv setting is on the server open.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instruction to check what you get as arguments:

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

From the official documentation, this is available as well as : `$_SERVER['argv']`.

Please also note that `$argv` and `$argc` need to be declared global, while trying to access within a class method.

Comment: NULL, when i do this i see the returned result is null , ["argv"]=> array(0) { } ["argc"]=> int(0)

Comment: I have tried these methods many times but I could not get the token.

Comment: Are you using the script in the right way? usually the first arg should be the script name if calling from the cli.

Comment: I think I use the methods correctly. There is nothing very detailed anyway, creating and calling tokens.
But I couldn't take the token here and the arg variable is constantly undefined or null
This is my main problem. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example how you are calling the script from the CLI?

Comment: hmm CLI? I think I did nothing in this part.
What I do is to download the library, open a file in ftp, upload the library and files to this folder then I created a token and called the token it's all here: http://www.ismailcakir.com/jwt/

Comment: How do you manage to receive the input from your script? if you use 'argv' or 'argc', means you need to run a scrip from the CLI. If you want to receive the input from a GET request or Post request, it's something different, also if you receive the input (token) parameter from an external call, using file_input with JSON call. So it's about how you manage to receive the argument. what you have posted does not indicate properly how you are receiving the parameter!

Comment: sorry... Jwt is a subject I don't know much about and I'm trying to learn.
Now I have updated my question and wrote exactly what happened on the file.

Comment: http://www.ismailcakir.com/jwt/test2.php?action=stuff displays : Please provide a key to verify. What is the source code behind? Seems that your method created a default token successfully, what the step after that?

Comment: Shouldn't I get the coin I created here? It gives me a key alert because I can't get the token.
When I remove this warning, I see `$ _SERVER ['argv'] [1]` is null.
and i can't get token
result: `{"jwt": null, "status": "error", "message": "Wrong number of segments"}`

Comment: I don't get it! Where are you seeing the warnings?

Comment: please click: http://www.ismailcakir.com/jwt/test2.php?action=stuff

Comment: It seems that the token provided and token generated are not well-validated. You have to check your validation again the token provided and generated.

Comment: You have to check your validation again the token.... the problem is I can't get this token `$ _SERVER ['argv'] [1]` null

Comment: or ... Can you write me a little code where I can create a token and authenticate with this token?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get the token with:

`$ _SERVER ['argv'] [1]`

Then, you need to run the script from the command line (CLI), i.e.: `php <script_name> argc1 arg2 ...`, then you will be able to the parameters values from there, if you use a browser, or an API call, you need to use an HTTP method (GET/POST),

Or with a JSON receiving call:

`file_get_contents("php://input");`

It seems that you put everything in your code, your code needs to be reformulated.

If you generate the token in a file script, and you need to send it back to a different page, you need to use a GET/POST request, if the user provides a value and you need to save it or use it, you need to receive it with a method, below an example about how your code can work properly (many ways could be provided):

```
 if ($action == 'login') {

 $email = 'freaky@jolly.com';
 $password = '12345678';


if($email == "freaky@jolly.com" && $password == "12345678"){

     $iat = time(); // time of token issued at
     $nbf = $iat + 10; //not before in seconds
     $exp = $iat + 60; // expire time of token in seconds

     $token = array(
         "iss" => "http://example.org",
         "aud" => "http://example.com",
         "iat" => $iat,
         "nbf" => $nbf,
         "exp" => $exp,
             "data" => array(
             "id" => 11,
             "email" => $email
         )
     );

    http_response_code(200);

    $jwt = JWT::encode($token, SECRET_KEY);

    $_SESSION['token'] = $jwt;
    // $_COOKIE['token'] = $jwt ;
    // GET and POST can be used via a web form or CURL

     $data_insert=array(
         'access_token' => $jwt, 
         'id'   => '007',
         'name' => 'Jolly',
         'time' => time(),
         'username' => 'FreakyJolly', 
         'email' => 'contact@freakyjolly.com', 
         'status' => "success",
         'message' => "Successfully Logged In"
     );


 }else{
     $data_insert=array(
     "data" => "0",
     "status" => "invalid",
     "message" => "Invalid Request"
     ); 
 } 

} else if($action == 'stuff'){

   /*
    * How to receive the generated token
    */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token']))
    // or (!isset($_POST['token']));
    // or (!isset($_GET['token'])); 
    // or (!isset($_COOKIE['token']));
    {
        exit('Please provide a key to verify');
    }

    $jwt = $_SESSION['token']; 

    // or $jwt = $_GET['token']; 
    // or $jwt = $_POST['token']; 
    // or $jwt = $_COOKIE['token'];

    try {
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, SECRET_KEY, array(ALGORITHM));
        print_r($decoded);

    }catch (Exception $e){

     http_response_code(401);
     $data_insert=array(
     //"data" => $data_from_server,
     "jwt" => $jwt,
     "status" => "error",
     "message" => $e->getMessage()
     );

   } 
}

echo json_encode($data_insert);
```

You can take a look on:

REST API Authentication Example in PHP – JWT Tutorial

`https://www.codeofaninja.com/2018/09/rest-api-authentication-example-php-jwt-tutorial.html`

Comment: Does it make sense to use cookies or a season?
These values are deleted when the browser is closed.
Is it possible to get the token every time with `$_POST` or `$_GET` when I open the browser again? **My main goal is that I don't want the user to have to log in every time.**

Comment: I made a browser-based application and users are logging into it. But I don't want them to log in every time. For this reason, I wanted to verify with JWT without using season or cookies.

Comment: Cookies and Sessions are not deleted when browsers is closed (only session storage). Session is active while it's not expired or the machine is not restarted, Or not closed programmatically.

Comment: If you need to use JWT for authentication, then you have to provide the token in each request (typical use for JWT is to provide it with the Authorization Header as Bearer TOKEN). Then you have to make a REST API . You cannot mix all requests and fashions then you expect everything to work as normal.

Comment: I have edited the response above at the end and provided a useful link to achieve the use of JWT as a REST Service.